# Как настроить phpstorm2016 на дебаг https?

Tags: phpstorm, xdebug

Настраиваю [xdebug](/questions/tagged/xdebug) в связке с [phpstorm](/questions/tagged/phpstorm) и хочу, чтобы при нажатии "Run -> Debug" сайты открывались в браузере по протоколу https, а не http.

На данный момент настройки шторма:

сервер
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

конфиг

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как видно из второй картинки, он автоматом ставит стартовый URL: **http**://test.lo/. Как переделать на https?

Хочу заметить, что сайты с http дебажатся вполне себе, т.е. дебаг настроен.
Также если нажать `Debug`, а потом в открытой сессий дебага дописать букву `s`, чтоб перейти на https, то тоже подхватится. Но каждый раз так добавлять букву не вариант.

Comment: Алексей, а что значит сайты дебажаться нормально. вы разрабатываете апи и тестируете его,  для чего это вам ?  Если можно киньте ссылку на годную статью по этой теме.

Comment: Так а если в стартовом урле написать полный, а не относительный, не прокатит?

Comment: @stack-it ну не глобальные сайты конечно дебажатся...)) Имеется в виду, что на тех сайтах, которые установлены на локальном сервере и открываются по адресу http://....  - отладка работает вполне себе и при нажатии на `Debug` открывается браузер на нужном адресе и начинается отладка.. а если сайт локально стоит и он открывается только через https, то я не знаю где в пхпшторм крутить крутилки для открытия правильного url

Comment: @D-side точно. кажется должно получится. хотя не люблю абсолют, но этот вариант должен сработать

Answer (score 6, accepted):

PHPStorm понимает полный URL с протоколом.

```
Start Url: https://test.lo/
```

И на всякий случай в настройках сервера еще выставить 443 порт.

Comment: да, абсолютный путь правда помог. порт 443 даже не понадобился